# In Mapbox, where do you set if callout dismissal is animated or not?

Tags: ios, mapbox

In the Mapbox `MGLCalloutView` protocol, the method to animate the dismissal of the callout view exists:

```
func dismissCallout(animated: Bool) {

    if animated {
        // perform animation
    } else {
        removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

However, where is the `animated` parameter originally set? Where do I set that boolean true or false?

Comment: Why do you want to know? Is there some functionality you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you allow the map to dismiss the callout, `animated` is set automatically. If you wanted to handle this yourself, you would call [`-[MGLMapView deselectAnnotation:animated:]`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.6.4/Classes/MGLMapView.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapView(im)deselectAnnotation:animated:) on the annotation that the callout is being presented from.